# Problemas con las texturas del terreno en Unity 5.6.7f1 Windows

Tags: unity3d, unity

He descargado recientemente Unity 5 para hacer unas pruebas, soy nuevo en esto apenas. Vi un video sobre como poner terreno pero no logro darle las texturas que se supone debo tener como por defecto, que seria la grama y otros mas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal tienes que importar la textura que quieras para añadirla. Prueba a descargar el "Standard Assets". Entre muchas otras cosas existen texturas para el terreno. Y si puedo preguntarte algo, ¿por qué usas Unity 5?

Comment: Listo, es que descarge unity individualmente y no tenia los assets basicos. Uso unity 5 porque es la que me corre en esta pc de 32 bits

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado. Da la pregunta como contestada, así se evitará que entren otras personas a intentar contestarla. ¡Suerte con tu proyecto!